# overflow:hidden doesn't work inside a table

Tags: css, html, overflow, hidden

When I try the code below, hiding the overflow doesn't work (it expands):

```
<table width="1024" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="1024" height="100" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td width="1024">
    <div style="width:1024;height:436;overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="position:absolute;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
    <td width="51"><img src="images/page1_04.jpg" width="51" height="436" /></td>
    <td width="922" height="437"><img src="images/page1_05.jpg" width="922" height="436" /></td>
    <td width="51"><img src="images/page1_06.jpg" width="51" height="436" onMouseOver="this.src='images/hover/page1_arrow_hover_06.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/page1_06.jpg'" /></td>
    <td width="300"><img src="images/page2_05.jpg" /></td>
    <td width="51"><img src="images/page2_04.jpg" width="51" height="436"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/hover/page2_arrow_hover_04.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/page2_04.jpg'" /></td>
    <td width="922" height="437"><img src="images/page2_05.jpg" width="922" height="436" /></td>
    <td width="51"><img src="images/page2_06.jpg" width="51" height="436" /></td>
    </tr></table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, when I use only a fragment of the code (the parent div) it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Mark.

Comment: You've made the inner div be `absolute`, which means it's no longer bound by the document flow, or its parent div's width/height settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set style with `table-layout:fixed; along with overflow:hidden;` on the table element.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment! If I understood you right the table should be: <table width="1024" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"> but it is still not working. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Thank you all guys! It's about adding "table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden;" in table style, making the DIV's position relative & keeping deleting the parent DIV. You are the best!

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<td  width="1024" height="100" style="display:block; overflow:hidden;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

.city {overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */} SELAMAT DATANG PADA PERPUSTAKAAN DIGITAL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).